# Excel Read Data based on time and name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where we maintain details of all the projects and resources. I need to know if a resource is free between the projects.
Assume there are x people in a team and I need to know for what duration someone is available in between the projects and when is persons next project starting.

Example:
Table 1: Details of project and resource

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Project</td>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>End Date</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>01 Jan 2019</td>
    <td>31 Mar 2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>05 Jan 2019</td>
    <td>01 May 2019</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Z</td>
    <td>15 Apr 2019</td>
    <td>01 Sep 2019</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In Above case person A has two projects X and Z and in between has 15 days’ time. I would like a table like below.

Table 2:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Current Project</td>
    <td>End Date</td>
    <td>Next Project</td>
    <td>Start Date</td>
    <td>Duration</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>X</td>
    <td>31 Mar 2019</td>
    <td>Z</td>
    <td>15 Apr 2019</td>
    <td>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>01 May 2019</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If Next project is not allocated, then Next Project, start date and Duration can be blank.
I don’t want to write VBA for this, I would like to use functions only to get this. Is it possible?

Comment: What if A has 3 projects?

Comment: A bit of a different approach, but it sounds like you would benefit from a [Gantt chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gantt_chart)

Comment: @Dcoder Did any of the answers below help?

Answer (score 0):

I've turned your data into an Excel Table (using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keyboard shortcut) and used the following formulas:

[image]

E2: `=IF(MAX(([Name]=[@Name])*([Start Date]>[@[End Date]])*[Start Date])>0,MAX(([Name]=[@Name])*([Start Date]>[@[End Date]])*[Start Date]),"")`

F2: `=IF(ISNUMBER([@[Next Project Start Date]]),[@[Next Project Start Date]]-[@[End Date]],"")`

Note that the formula in E2 is an array-entered formula: You must enter it into Excel using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's no need to get the third project. First you should get unique names (column `A`). This can be done like [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list) or by using `unique()` function in case of Google Sheet. Assuming the input range is `Sheet1!A2:A9`, on `Sheet2` you can get the first name (`A` in this case) by entering below array formula at `A2`:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9), 0)),"")}
```

Now add a helper column `G` in `Sheet2`. On `G2` enter below formula to get the current matching row index for the first name(`A`):

```
=MATCH($A2, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9, 0)
```

Add another helper column `H`. You can get the next matching row index for the first name(`A`) like this (on `H2`):

```
=MATCH($A2, OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9, $G2, 0, 8), 0)+$G2
```

Note that `8` is the hard-coded height of `Sheet1!$A$2:$A$9`. If input range changes, you should change the value too.

Now you have can get current project name like this (on `B2`):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9, $G2)
```

And the next project name (on `D2`):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$9, $H2)
```

Current project end date (on `C2`):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$9, $G2)
```

Next project start date (on `E2`):

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$9, $H2)
```

Then duration is trivial (on `F2`):

```
=E2-C2
```

Then copy `2:2` and paste onto `3:9`. Done.

[image]

Sample file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/movrczps4zlxg2h/51139506.xlsx?dl=0). I've wrapped every cell by `ifError()` In the file.